# How to resolve Http Load Balancing Error 1003 on cloudflare dns?

Tags: load-balancing, cloudflare

SSL/TLS encryption mode on Cloudflare side is on "flexible" status (https on)

server side setting on third server is:

```
upstream backend {
  server domain1.com;
  server domain2.com;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
 }
```

Error message is:
**Error 1003
Direct IP access not allowed**

Cloudflare explains:
Error 1003 Access Denied: Direct IP Access Not Allowed
Common cause
A client or browser directly accesses a Cloudflare IP address.
Resolution
Browse to the website domain name in your URL instead of the Cloudflare IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem with set proxy to the header

```
proxy_set_header Host www.domain.io;
```